# Mismatch of types between actual function and test function

Tags: go, kubernetes-go-client

I have written the following function. Its does the following

1. Traverse through a given namespace and iterate through all pods.
2. Return a string slice containing pods that match a naming convention.

```
var slavePods []string

func getSlavePods(clientset *kubernetes.Clientset, ns string, release string) []string {
    log.Printf("INFO :: Checking slave pods in %s namespace.\n", ns)
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(ns).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for _, po := range pods.Items {
        SlavePodRegex := "zjs-" + release + "-(tiny|small|medium|large)-(.*)"
        log.Printf("INFO :: Regex is %s", SlavePodRegex)
        matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(SlavePodRegex , po.Name)
        if matched{
            slavePods = append(slavePods, po.Name)
        }
    }

    return slavePods
}
```

In the above case, the clientset is of type `*"k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes".Clientset`

The above functions works well and returns the required result.

Now I am writing a test for this function. The test is

```
import (
    "context"
    v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake"
    "log"
    "testing"
)

func TestgetSlavePods(t *testing.T) {

    // Create the fake client.
    client := fake.NewSimpleClientset()

    // Inject an event into the fake client.
    p := &v1.Pod{ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{Name: "zjs-modelt-develop-small-n3d8t"}}
    _, err := client.CoreV1().Pods("test-ns").Create(context.TODO(), p, metav1.CreateOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("error injecting pod add: %v", err)
    }

     // Actual test
     podNames := getSlavePods(client, "test-ns", "modelt-develop")
     if podNames != ["zjs-modelt-develop-small-n3d8t"] {
         t.Error("Expected pod is not found")
     }
}
```

I am leveraging the fake library to initialize a fake client, create a pod in a namespace and then test the function. But I am getting an error

```
Cannot use 'client' (type *"k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake".Clientset) as type *"k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes".Clientset
```

So seems like there is an issue where I cannot invoke the function with the `clientset` because the types are different in the actual function v/s the test function. I am following [this example](https://github.com/profefe/kube-profefe/tree/master/pkg/kubeutil) and they seem to be doing the samething. Is there something I have missed ?

Comment: `*kubernetes.Clientset` is a pointer to a struct, i.e. a concrete type. Such a type cannot be replaced at runtime with another type because Go is a statically typed language.

Comment: But in the example I mentioned, they are doing the same and it works there, no ?

Comment: *"I am following this example and they seem to be doing the samething."* Look again, they are using `kubernetes.Interface` and you're using `*kubernetes.Clientset`, what about that is the "samething"? Or is it *me* that's missing something?

Comment: I understand your point now. Thats what I missed. Thanks